# working of read-write sets in hyperledger

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, read-write

Can anyone explain how read-write set and version numbers are used in hyperledger with respect to endorsement and validation with an use-case ?

Comment: Could you give more information about what you want?! I'm sorry about my English, but I don't understan your question. Have you got any example about what you don't understand?

Comment: I am also interested in this questions, documentation is not good enough. It should be explained in more easy way in not so mathematically.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric read/write sets are described [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readwrite.html).